# Execution time comparison of binary and linear search

Tags: c, time

I have written the two functions 'linearSearch' & 'binarySearch' and now want to compare their execution time difference. I have used time.h library of C.
But problem is the time of execution is always getting printed 0.0000! I'm not getting it.

```
int main()
{
    clock_t start,end;
    float cpu_time_used;
    int a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    start = clock();
    printf("%d",binarySearch(a,5,4));
    end = clock();
    cpu_time_used = ((float) (end - start)/ CLOCKS_PER_SEC)*1000;
    printf("\nTime binary : %f milliseconds",cpu_time_used);

    start = clock();
    printf("\n%d",linearSearch(a,5,4));
    end = clock();
    cpu_time_used = ((float) (end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC)*1000;
    printf("\nTime linear : %f milliseconds",cpu_time_used);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's because your list is so small that even a linear search complete in less than a milliseconds. Try a bigger list.

Comment: I’d expect the call to `clock` to take much longer than the actual search, and all of those to be overwhelmed by the I/O.

Comment: Note also that the performance difference between linear and binary search, considered as general algorithms, is a matter of asymptotic complexity (O(n) *vs*. O(log n)).  Thus, you may need a considerably larger problem to see it at all, regardless of the precision of and noise in your timing measurement.

Comment: int a[] =      {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,40,41,44,45,48,32,39,72,73};
 int size = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);

Comment: I have used this but again 0.000.

Comment: I have also used numbers from 1 to 1000!!

Comment: Again same I think problem may be somewhere in the algorithm not the input ?

Comment: @MrityunjoyNath 1000 is still quite small for modern machines. Have you tried something like 10000, 100000 or even a million? Also, try to test the worst case scenario and search of something that is not in your test array.

Comment: You might also consider running each search many times, in a loop.  Not only will that help accumulate enough execution time to actually be observable, but it will also help average out timing variances in the individual runs.

Comment: Computers are really fast.